# Получение данных Московской биржи через API

Tags: api, pandas, поиск-api

Использую  [Pandas DataReader](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pandas-datareader/stable/pandas-datareader.pdf), который содержит какие то исторические данные, однако многие тикеры отсутствуют - например Сбербанк (RU0009029540), FXUS (IE00BD3QHZ91).

Есть ли бесплатные альтернативы для получения относительно свежих данных московской биржи?

Answer (score 1):

Несмотря на то, что написано в примерах, нужно использовать символьный код тикеров, а не ISIN, т.е `SBER`  вместо `RU0009029540`.